# Перебор пар значений из двух списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно чтобы сначала из 1 цикла бралось одно значение, а потом из второго, и это повторялось каждый раз. В этом коде такая последовательность выполняется только тогда, когда заканчивается файл sc_base.txt, потом производится первый цикл и опять запускает второй.

```
import os
import requests
import time
_iter_ = 5
password = input("Введите пароль: ")
numbers = open("sc_base.txt", "r").readlines()
proxies = open("proxy_test.txt", "r").readlines()
for proxy_list in proxies:
    s = requests.Session()
    d = s.proxies.update({'http': 'http://' + proxy_list})
    print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    for login in numbers:
        print(proxy_list)
        print(login)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: /* включаю миелофон */ наверно, вам надо во внешнем цикле перебирать значения из numbers, а во вложенном — из proxies. так в чём тогда трудность?

Comment: Трудность в том, что если я делаю так, как вы сказали, то весь список proxies перебирается, берётся последнее значение, а потом берётся значение из numbers и так по циклу, тоесть proxies последнее значение, а numbers по очереди, а нужно что бы всё было по очереди

Comment: вы приводите какие-то очень непонятные описания, приведите лучше [mcve] (т.е., без всяких дополнительных файлов, запросов в интернет и тому подобного). исправить текст вопроса — [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос не очень понятен, но, скорее всего он как обычно про параллельное итерирование двух последовательностей, которое в питоне делается с помощью функции `zip`:

```
for proxy_list,login in zip(proxies,numbers):
    print(proxy_list)
    print(login)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Хотя что вы пытаетесь сделать строчкой `d = s.proxies.update({'http': 'http://' + proxy_list})` для меня осталось загадкой.